# How to access the Card section input field value in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

My card builder looks something like

```
function createSelectionCard(e) {
  var builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();

  builder.addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName("text_input_form_input_key")
      .setTitle("Enter Value")
      .setValue('Test'))
....
return builder.build();
```

The [documentation for Text Input](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input#detailed-documentation) says that `setFieldName` `Sets the key that identifies this text input in the event object that is generated when there is a UI interaction` but using `e.text_input_form_input_key` always results to a null value

```
function Embed(e) {
...
  presentation.getSelection().getCurrentPage().insertImage(dataBlob)
    .setDescription(e.text_input_form_input_key)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the imputed value from a text input, you need `e.formInputs.name`:

> For example, your add-on can locate the text a user has entered into a TextInput widget in the `eventObject.commentEventObject.formInputs` object.

To give you an idea, you can try with the following:

```
e.commonEventObject.formInputs.text_input_form_input_key.stringInputs.value[0]
```

For more details, you can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#common_event_object).

**References:**
[Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects)